# How to include css class to django forms

Tags: python, css, django

I'm using Django Password Reset view to reset user's password. It's working perfectly fine, I've included the predefined Password reset class in my urls.py. I want to design the fields of the form, since I don't have forms.py, I can't give css attribute to the form field. Can I get help?

Comment: You need to create another form which should be inherited from the built-in password reset form.

Comment: That's the issue since I'm new to Django, Creating such model Form is easier. But for predefined forms, I don't know the field name to target.